# gfortran linking and compiling subprograms in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, fortran, mingw, gfortran

I would like to compile and run fortran subprograms using Visual Studio code.

When I try debugging the code, I get an error stating that the "*prelaunch task 'gfortran' terminated with exit code 1*", with the following console message:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process "C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe '-g', 'D:\......\params.f95', '-o', 'D:\.......\params.exe'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

When I click 'show errors' it says that 'no problems have been detected in the worskpace so far'

My json file configurations for the folder are as follows:
Launch.json

```
    {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Fortran Launch (GDB)",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "targetArchitecture": "x86",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "miDebuggerPath": "gdb.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "externalConsole": true,
                "preLaunchTask": "gfortran"
            }
        ]
       }
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "command": "gfortran",   

    "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceRoot}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
    ]
   }
```

I tried many of the fixes found from the web, such as changing the default setting to save file before run, reinstalling gfortran etc., but to no avail. When I try compiling from the command prompt, I do not have any errors, but when I use the flag -g, I have the same error about '*undefined reference to WinMain@16*'. Also, I have no problem using the settings to run a single fortran code (without subprograms).

I have a Windows-32 architecture, and I have used MinGW to install gfortran. I have set the System Environment Variable 'Path' to include this folder.

I hope the problem is clear, please help me with this.

Comment: Does your Fortran code actually contain a `program`? You do not show your code. You write you want to *"run fortran subprograms"* but you cannot ride subprograms, you need a program. We have other questions and answers about that.

Comment: I have a program a.f95, which includes two subprograms (modules) - params.f95 to declare the parameters, and subroutes.f95 to define the subroutines

Comment: All programs written completely in Fortran must have one, and only one, program unit, usually  delimited by "Program" and "End Program". This calls the other units in the program in the required order. Do you have such a unit? If not you will typically get an error similar to the one you report - which to me indicates either you have no program unit, or you do have one but your build system is not finding it.

Comment: Yes, I have this... my program unit is a.f95, and it calls the modules params and subroutes. I have no problem in running the code using FTN95 compiler, from SilverFrost. But I want to use gfortran in order to enable OpenMP applications

Comment: I am able to compile and execute from the command line, using -c and -o flags. But I have the same error when I use the -g flag to debug.